# How to apply custom fonts (Proximanova.woff file using @Font-Face) while replacing css of HTML response with custom CSS in Desktop Application?

Tags: html, css, javafx, font-face, font-family

I have started working on Desktop Application using JavaFx. In one of the screens, a part of it is loaded by HTML Response got by PHP Webservice Call.  My aim is to replace css file of the HTML response with custom css file. All the properties are getting reflected except @font-face (Proximanova.woff) . I am posting the piece of code for the above problem.
Let me know why that proximanova.woff font not getting applied. Thanks in advance!

HTML Response.

```
<html subtitle="Please type your activation code in the text box below and click 'Next'.  ">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>promotion activation</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="promotion.css" />
    
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
                var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
          evt.initEvent("TTUpdateButton", true, false);
         document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }, true);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
            <button id="TTButton_continue" disabled="true"
            onclick="onButtonEvent('right')"
            style="display: none;">
        Next            </button>
                    <div id="code-body">
    <div id="code-box">
        <form name="fcode" id="code-fcode" method="post" onsubmit="return isCodeValid();">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="validate" />
            <div id="code-textbox">
                <span>
                    Your activation code                        </span>
                <input
                       class="field"
                       type="text"
                       name="sCode"
                       id="code"
                       value=""
                       onchange="onInputChange();"
                       onkeyup="onInputChange();"
                />
            </div>
        </form>

        
        <div id="code-text">
           As soon as you activate your code, the associated product will be available for download and/or use.<a href=# onClick="Javascript:onMoreInfoLinkClick()">Learn how you can get your activation code here.</a>                </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.fcode)
    {
        document.fcode.sCode.focus();
    }

    var initialCodeValue = "";
    
    function isCodeValid()
    {
        var theRawValue = document.fcode.sCode.value;
        
        // Don't enable the next button if nothing has changed
        if (theRawValue == initialCodeValue)
            return false;
        initialCodeValue = "";

        theUpperCaseValue = theRawValue.toUpperCase(); //we need first to clean the input like we do server side

        theValue = (theUpperCaseValue.replace(/\W+/g,''));
        return (theValue.search(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}$|^NC[0-9]{10}$|^CC[0-9]{16}$/) == 0);
    }
    
    function writeScriptOpenTomTomHelpLink()
    {
        var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
           evt.initEvent("TTHelpLink", true, false);
           document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
    function onMoreInfoLinkClick(){
        writeScriptOpenTomTomHelpLink();
    }
    
    function onInputChange()
    {
        var valid = isCodeValid();
        var theButtonElement = document.getElementById("TTButton_continue");
        if (valid)
            theButtonElement.removeAttribute("disabled");
        else
            theButtonElement.setAttribute("disabled", true);
            var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
 evt.initEvent("TTUpdateButton", true, false);
      document.documentElement.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
    
    function onButtonEvent(buttonName)
    {
        document.fcode.submit();
    }
    
    window.addEventListener("load", onInputChange, false);
</script>

    </body>
```

MyActivationCode.css (Custom CSS file created that is used for replacement)

```
     @font-face {
    font-family: "proxima";
    src: url('/proximanova-regular.woff');
}

body {
    font-family: "proxima"; 
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 13px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: proxima;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666666;
}

.additional-offer {
    border-top: 3px #dedede solid;
}

.select-country, .select-product {
    padding: 5px 10px 15px 10px;
}

#code-text {
    margin: 5px 2px 5px 2px;
    font-family: proxima;
}

#code-textbox {
    font-family: "proxima";
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    color: #878787;
}

#code-textbox span {
    font-family: proxima;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #666666;
}

#code-fcode {
    display: table-row;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}

#code-error {
    color: #ff0000;
    margin: 0px 2px 5px 2px;
    font-family: proxima;
}

#traffic-error {
    color: #ff0000;
    margin: 0px 2px 5px 2px;
    font-family: proxima;
}

#message-text {
    margin: 5px 2px 5px 2px;
    font-family: proxima;
}

#message-header {
    font-family: proxima;
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666666;
}
```

DeviceController.java that is making php webservice call

```
   public class DeviceController extends BaseController {


    @Override
    protected void doInitialize() {
        super.doInitialize();
       
        getActivePhpServiceCall();
       
    }



    /**
     * Gets the active php service call.
     *
     * @return the active php service call
     */
    protected void getActivePhpServiceCall() {
        new ActivationService().activationCodeService(new FutureCallback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void failed(Exception ex) {
                LOGGER.error("Failed to call Activation code service: {}", ex);
              

            }

            @Override
            public void completed(String result) {
                new ActivationCodeHelper().handleBackForActivationCodeService(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void cancelled() {
                LOGGER.debug("Activation code service call is cancelled");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ActivationCodeHelper.java (File that is reading html response and replacing the css file)

```
public class ActivationCodeHelper extends BaseHelper {

    /**
     * Handle back for activation code service.
     *
     * @param result the result
     */
    public void handleBackForActivationCodeService(String result) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        
            String cssURL = "";
            try {
                cssURL = globalContext.fileUtil().getFileContents(Paths
                        .get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("css/MyActivationCode.css").toURI()).toString());
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(cssURL.toString());

        
            File cssFile = globalContext.fileUtil().fileWriter(".css", cssURL);
            File file = globalContext.fileUtil().fileWriter(".html",
                    result.replaceAll("promotion.css", cssFile.getName()));
            map.put("cssFile", cssFile.getName());
            map.put("UseMyActivation", file.toURI().toString());
            redirectToActivationScreen(map);

    }
    
    }
```

Comment: Why javafx tag?

Comment: Since the HTML Response is being rendered in Desktop application, I included JavaFx .

Comment: You mean that you are rendering HTML in a JavaFX WebView and this question has nothing to do with JavaFX CSS?  What you are asking then, is why the CSS file you create does not cause the WebView to render the proxima font when you display some HTML in it?  Better to have a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, i.e., an app that includes the needed font as a resource and uses, in a web view, a local CSS file with just the font setting and a html file with just the text to which the font is applied.  To me, there doesn't seem to be a reason for anything more or less than that.

Comment: A [blog demoing how to apply fontface fonts in JavaFX](http://fxexperience.com/2012/12/use-webgoogle-fonts-in-javafx/), that loads the css stylesheets for the fonts from google, but you can use your own style sheets.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `./proximanova-regular.woff` or `proximanova-regular.woff`? javaFX might also be picky about the format and font-weight. Try `@font-face {
  font-family: "proxima";
  src: url('proximanova-regular.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight:400;
}`

Comment: Hi herrstrietzel , I tried adding the above @font-face definition. Also, I have placed proximanova-regular.woff in **src/main/resources/css/** package.  But, still fonts are  not rendering in prominovaregular .

Comment: Alternate Solution found : if src is calling the softlink to fetch the proximanova font then, fonts are rendering properly.  [link] https://codepen.io/gopalakannan/pen/eYYVBXa          **But, I am expecting the solution using .woff file**

Comment: I tried with specifying the complete path like this--> **src: url('/project-ui/src/main/resources/css/new-fonts/proximanova-regular.woff') format('woff');**   But, no luck!!! @herrstrietzel   Any proper reason why it is not rendering in proximanova? Please assist!

Comment: Can you try a local ttf instead? If you're importing/using the font in the "native" window application environment (and not displaying text within a browser-like view) you'll need a windows compatible font format like truetype or otf. Otherwise JavaFX might expect another path to load the font loacally.

Comment: Hi @herrstrietzel , local .ttf file also didn't work. I had to create Softlink URL to render the font.